# How to calculate an orthogonal basis for any scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$ with a scalar product $<,>$. We know from theory that it's always possible to determine an orthogonal basis with respect to $<,>$, for any scalar product. Even more, if $K = ℝ$ we can choose a basis $B = \{v_1,...,v_n \}$  s.t. the matrix associated to $<,>$ for $B$ is a diagonal matrix having on the main diagonal only $1, -1$ or $0$, while if $K = ℂ$, we can choose a basis $C = \{w_1,...,w_n \}$ s.t. the matrix associated to $<,>$ for $C$ is a diagonal matrix having on the main diagonal only $1$ or $0$. My question is: is there a standard method to determine these bases, for any real or complex vector space and for any scalar product?

(I just know that if $V = ℝ^n$ a basis as $B$ is composed of orthogonal eigenvectors of $A$, where $A$ is the matrix of $<,>$ with respect to the canonical base)

Comment: What do you know about the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: A basis is not required to be orthogonal, they merely have to be linearly independent. If we have a uniform distribution on the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that we can pick $n$ vectors at random then they will form a basis. If you want an orthonormal basis use Gram-Schmidt on a randomly selected basis.

Comment: I know the Gram-Schmidt process, but does it work if the scalar product is not positive definite or if the field is not R?

Comment: If your scalar product is not positive definite, is it an inner product?

Comment: If you mean non-degenerate, no, it could be any kind of scalar product on R or C.